# How can I get the lock screen sounds from Android 4.3 back? (upgraded to 4.4)

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat

I have a Nexus 7 and I updated to android 4.4 after the upfate had been downloaded and waiting for a week. I miss the crisp sounds of the 4.3 lock screen, it made me like my device. Now its all changed without warning and I'm upset left feeling like my device isn't really mine. Is there a way to fix this? Likewise time/battery/WiFi icons at top have changed from blue to gray. Anyway to change just these two aspects without rooting or factory reset? Thanks.

Comment: A factory-reset will not help you for either of them. Both are intentional design changes with Kitkat – so you either can have Kitkat with those, or downgrade to 4.3 to get your former feelings back, sorry. While there might be ways for the sounds (if you can get hold of the sound files, and set them accordingly), there's no way for the notification area (at least not without root) I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably download a custom Rom from [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7/development) and find and extract the sound files from

```
/system/media/audio/
```

You should be able to put them into the relevant folder on the 'sdcard'

```
/sdcard/alarms/
/sdcard/Notifications/
/sdcard/Ringtones/
```

where they will get picked up by the OS.

As for the notification icons, without rooting and customising the relevant files (I'm not sure exactly which) there is no way to change them from white to blue.

Comment: I think some of the sounds are actually part of system APK's and would require recompiling the specific parts of the system, or perhaps something with Xposed Framework. The same can be said of notification icons. I could easily be wrong about the sounds though.

Answer (score 1):

WidgetLocker will allow you to adjust the lock screen sounds, the only downside is you can't use it with a pin. The status bar was a change to make android look better, you can't change that without changing ROMs or using Xposed Framework.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker

Answer (score 0):

System sounds are stored in a folder accessible without root. I forget the path, but all you have to do is replace the files with the sound you want.

Comment: The path would be required to answer this question.